# Mongoose Variable Sort

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to sort based on a variable the user enters. I have something like this:

```
var find = Record.find(query);
```

The following works just fine:

```
find.sort({age: 1});
```

It sorts by age. I want to do the following:

```
find.sort({sortField: 1});
```

I've tried this as well:

```
find.sort[sortField] = 1;
```

To no luck. Any way to set sort with a string variable passed in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're using node v4+, you can use the ES6 [enhanced literal syntax](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals) support for computed property names:

```
find.sort({[sortField]: 1});
```

Otherwise you need to create your sort object in a couple steps:

```
var sort = {};
sort[sortField] = 1;
find.sort(sort);
```

Comment: It’s a big thank. And I might add adding the [ ] for the sort order condition will help you to get that one also from a dynamic variable.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Can't use the find.sort[sortField] = 1 notation since it's a function, need to do that ahead of time.

```
    var sort = {};
    sort[sortField] = 1;
    find.sort(sort);
```